# Toshiba Z835-300 will not boot

Tags: toshiba-laptop

My new Toshiba z835 refuses to boot. When I power it up, the Toshiba logo is displayed and immediately after on the upper left corner of the screen the word PASSWORD: is displayed.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a BIOS password set on the laptop.  Presumably, this is your laptop, so you should know the password.  If you set it by mistake, you will likely need to contact Toshiba technical support to have it removed.  BIOS passwords cannot usually be removed using alternate boot media; this would defeat the purpose of having them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's new, return it to the store. I find it strange that someone would *accidentally* have set a password on a new laptop.

Comment: Depends on the OP's definition of "new". :)